# NEventStore SqlPersistence GetFrom Paging

Tags: cqrs, neventstore

I am streaming all events in my EventSTore with this:

```
eventStore.Advanced.GetFrom(DateTime.MinValue).ToArray().SelectMany(its => its.Events).ToArray();
```

Keeping the paging at the default 128 limits the number of events fetched at 2989. When I increase the paging size to 9000 I get all the events as I expect (there are around 7K events).

What is the best way of making sure I am getting *all* the events; ie when rebuilding view models?

BTW I am still on ES 2.0 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's the a bug in EventStore v2.0 related to paging that's causing the behavior you're seeing.  EventStore v3.0 fixes this bug.  Also, I would definitely avoid the .ToArray() on that call because if you have 100K+ events, you're asking for an OutOfMemoryException.

Once you're on EventStore v3.0, you can call GetFrom and iterate through the events and do something on each event, like update a set of DB tables, etc.

Comment: Thanks Jonathon, I'll bump up the version then. Thanks again for you work on this project.